# How to use SqlCommand to CREATE DATABASE with parameterized db name?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

To put it short. I've got two simple helpers:

```
    private SqlCommand CreateCommand(string text)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = text;
        return cmd;
    }

    void SetParameter(SqlCommand cmd, string p, string dbName)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p, SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters[p].Value = dbName;
    }
```

This executes OK:

```
var cmd = CreateCommand("CREATE DATABASE Demo "+
            @"ON (FILENAME = N'c:\demo_data.mdf') "+ 
            @"LOG ON (FILENAME = N'c:\demo_data.mdf.LDF') "+
            "FOR ATTACH " +
            "GO");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But this doesn't:

```
string dataBaseAttachText = "CREATE DATABASE @dbname " +
                              "ON (FILENAME = @filename) " +
                              "LOG ON (FILENAME = @filenamelog) " +
                              "FOR ATTACH GO";
var cmd = CreateCommand(dataBaseAttachText);

SetParameter(cmd, "@dbname", "Demo");
SetParameter(cmd, "@filename", @"c:\demo_data.mdf");
SetParameter(cmd, "@filenamelog", @"c:\demo_data.mdf.LDF");

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do something like: USE @databaseName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788566/how-can-i-do-something-like-use-databasename)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Parameters are supported for DML operations not DDL operations, there are no execution plans for DDL operations. you will need to use dynamic SQL

DDL =  Data Definition Language (create, drop, alter....)

DML = Data Manipulation Language (select, update, delete, insert)

Comment: not really an answer to the question, Rich Hildebrand has better answer.

Answer (score 11):

Sadly you can accomplish this by wrapping your DDL operation in a DML operation.

```
var createDatabaseQuery = "exec ('CREATE DATABASE ' + @databaseName)";

var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(createDatabaseQuery, sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@databaseName", SqlDbType.Text);
sqlCommand.Parameters["@databaseName"].Value = "HelloWorld";

sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: While it looks like this approach provides protection against SQL injection (which using parameters does), it doesn't!

Answer (score 10):

You can only use parameters in places where SQL Server supports them.  Unfortunately SQL Server does not support parameterised `CREATE DATABASE` statements (although I have a feeling the filename parts *may* support parameters).

You'll need to construct the SQL yourself:

```
string dataBaseAttachText = "CREATE DATABASE [" + dbName + "] " + 
                              "ON (FILENAME = @filename) " + 
                              "LOG ON (FILENAME = @filenamelog) " + 
                              "FOR ATTACH GO"; 
var cmd = CreateCommand(dataBaseAttachText); 

SetParameter(cmd, "@filename", @"c:\demo_data.mdf"); 
SetParameter(cmd, "@filenamelog", @"c:\demo_data.mdf.LDF"); 

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

CAUTION: this is susceptable to SQL-injection attacks so caremust be taken; if you don't trust the source of the database name, don't do this!

You'll need to make similar changes to the filename parts if those can't be parameterised either.

Answer (score 5):

As a bit of a combination of both Daniel's and Rich's answer. By running a DML query to [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) you can have a dynamically built query, also by using [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) it should escape any attempts at sql injection someone may pass in.

```
string dataBaseAttachText = @"
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
SET @SQLString =
     N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + N' 
       ON (FILENAME = @filename) 
       LOG ON (FILENAME = @filenamelog) 
       FOR ATTACH GO'
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@filename nvarchar(MAX), @filenamelog nvarchar(MAX)'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @filename = @filename, @filenamelog = @filenamelog";

var cmd = CreateCommand(dataBaseAttachText); 

SetParameter(cmd, "@dbname", "Demo");
SetParameter(cmd, "@filename", @"c:\demo_data.mdf"); 
SetParameter(cmd, "@filenamelog", @"c:\demo_data.ldf"); 

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This should execute the following DML sql query with the proper parameters passed.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [Demo]
       ON (FILENAME = @filename) 
       LOG ON (FILENAME = @filenamelog) 
       FOR ATTACH GO
```

Comment: what assembly is CreateCommand part of? Is it available in .net 45

Comment: @user1591131 CreateComand is a function written at the top of this page in the question.

Comment: Did anyone try running this? There is a missing @ in `SET ParmDefinition...`. The whole thing makes no difference anyways, if we fix the mistake it just fails with 'Incorrect syntax near '@filename'.'

Comment: Stack overflow is a wiki anyone can edit any answer if you see an error in one

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating an extension method to wrap all entities appropriately.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Quotes the provided string in a sql friendly way using the standard [ and ] characters 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ObjectName">string to quote</param>
    /// <example>
    /// "mytable".QuoteSqlName() would return [mytable] 
    /// "my[complex]table".QuoteSqlName()  would return [my[[complex]]table]
    /// </example>
    /// <returns>quoted string wrapped by quoting characters</returns>
    /// <remarks>For dynamic sql this may need to be called multiple times, one for each level of encapsulation.</remarks>
    public static string QuoteSqlName(this string ObjectName)
    {
        return ObjectName.QuoteSqlName(']');
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Quotes the provided string in a sql friendly way using the provided character
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ObjectName">string to quote</param>
    /// <param name="QuoteCharacter">Character to quote with, use [ or ] for standard sql quoting</param>
    /// <example>
    /// "mytable".QuoteSqlName() would return [mytable] 
    /// "my[complex]table".QuoteSqlName()  would return [my[[complex]]table]
    /// "justin's computer".QuoteSqlName('\'') would return 'justin''s computer'
    /// </example>
    /// <returns>quoted string wrapped by quoting characters</returns>
    public static string QuoteSqlName(this string ObjectName, char QuoteCharacter)
    {
        return ObjectName.QuoteSqlName(QuoteCharacter, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Quotes the provided string in a sql friendly way using the provided character
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ObjectName">string to quote</param>
    /// <param name="QuoteCharacter">Character to quote with, use [ or ] for standard sql quoting</param>
    /// <param name="IsNvarChar">if true and QuoteCharacter is ' will prefix the quote with N e.g. N'mytable' vs 'mytable'</param>
    /// <example>
    /// "mytable".QuoteSqlName() would return [mytable] 
    /// "my[complex]table".QuoteSqlName()  would return [my[[complex]]table]
    /// "justin's computer".QuoteSqlName('\'') would return 'justin''s computer'
    /// "mytable".QuoteSqlName('\'',false) would reutrn 'mytable'
    /// "mytable".QuoteSqlName('[',true) would return [mytable]
    /// "mytable".QuoteSqlName('\'',true) would reutrn N'mytable'
    /// </example>
    /// <returns>quoted string wrapped by quoting characters</returns>
    public static string QuoteSqlName(this string ObjectName, char QuoteCharacter, bool IsNvarChar)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjectName))
            return ObjectName;

        char OtherQuoteCharacter = (char)0;
        bool UseOtherChar = false;
        if (QuoteCharacter == ']' || QuoteCharacter == '[')
        {
            QuoteCharacter = '[';
            OtherQuoteCharacter = ']';
            UseOtherChar = true;
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder((int)(ObjectName.Length * 1.5) + 2);
        if (QuoteCharacter == '\'' && IsNvarChar)
            sb.Append('N');

        sb.Append(QuoteCharacter); // start with initial quote character
        for (var i = 0; i < ObjectName.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(ObjectName[i]);
            // if its a quote character, add it again e.g. ] becomes ]]
            if (ObjectName[i] == QuoteCharacter || UseOtherChar && ObjectName[i] == OtherQuoteCharacter)
                sb.Append(ObjectName[i]);
        }
        sb.Append(UseOtherChar ? OtherQuoteCharacter : QuoteCharacter); // finish with other final quote character

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Usage:

```
var QuotedDBName = this.DBName.QuoteSqlName();
CreateDBQuery.AppendFormat("USE {0};", QuotedDBName);
CreateDBQuery.AppendFormat("IF TYPE_ID({0}) IS NULL", DBType.Name.QuoteSqlName('\'', true));
CreateDBQuery.AppendFormat("    CREATE TYPE {0} as {1};", DBType.Name.QuoteSqlName(), DBType.Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this task by calling the build in stored precedure 'sp_executesql'.
The connectionstring used to create DB points to 'master'.
The complete SQL statement is part of parameter value:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_executesql", connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var sql = $"CREATE DATABASE NewDatabaseName";
        command.Parameters.Add("MyParameterName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sql;
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```