# How to create a local SQL Server database in SharpDev?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sharpdevelop

I'm trying to follow the HeadFirst book by O'Reily but using SharpDev instead of Visual Studio. I'm on the 2nd edition and have done well up until this point.

Now the instructions are the following:

> We need a database to store our information.

So for Visual Studio, the instructions are:

1. In Solutions Explorer, right-click on project, select Add, and choose new Item.
2. Select SQL datbase and name it something.

I don't know how to replicate that in SharpDev. I assume that it doesn't come with its own SharpDev SQL Server Express, so I downloaded Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express. From that point on, I add a...database connection? I create a blank database in SQL Server 2008 Express?

What do I do to create my local database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Sql Server Management Studio.
2. Connect to your local Sql Server when the dialog prompts you.
3. In the Object Explorer select Databases, right click and select New Database.
4. Give it a name and select OK.

Another alternative would be to install Visual Studio Express which may allow you to follow the book without hitting missing features in SharpDevelop.

Comment: I installed Visual Studio Express in the end. I would still like to eventually adapt a simple database created into SharpDevelop but for now, for the purpose of learning, I appreciate the features of Visual Studio Express.

Comment: OK but... that is not really creating a DB using #develop. OP also could have helped a bit by not asking a general question under a specific titled question.

Comment: @CharlesRobertoCanato - SharpDevelop does not support creating a sql server database itself so another tool needs to be used or code written to do it. There are [existing answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015142/creating-a-database-programmatically-in-sql-server) on how to create a sql server database programmatically.