# How to create a DB in MySql at run time from VB?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, runtime

Good morning,
I'm developing a cms.
Before I was working with Access but I was limited so now I'm changing to MySql and I have some problems about the creation at run time of the db.
When I was using Access I connected with OLEDB and I used the object Adox to develop on the fly databases.
Now I don't know how to do, I found a lot of articles for Sql Server but nothing interesting for MySql.
Is it possbile to do it?
When I connect I must to put the name of db but I dont have yet.. so.. 
Anyone has already developed something similar?

Thank you

Comment: you must have some server.. first create database on that server, and then connect to it.. of course, vice versa is not possible.. use  MySQL commands to create database, tables, etc

Comment: I need to create db at run time each time I have new customer and it has to be all automatically, I have to do it from the code, so I think you didnt properly understand, or maybe I'm wrong

Comment: read that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600076/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-sql-server-without-specifying-a-database

Comment: Perfect, it works! easier then I thought, thank you! Can I ask you also if you can help me with my other thread? Thank you very much

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370725/how-can-i-set-same-values-in-all-character-set-and-collation-set-on-mysql