# populate database from sql server generated script

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

So I'm developing a web application where each user has it's own database. What i want is to automate the process of create the user specific database when he registers.

My idea is to create a new empty database with a custom name and then run a pre-made sql script to generate the tables and default values for this database.

**Edit**
I think I haven't been clear before.

I create the database as follows:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("data source=MySource; uid=MyUser; pwd=MyPassword;"))
   {
      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
      {
         conn.Open();
         cmd.Connection = conn;
         cmd.CommandText = "Create Database MYNewDB;";
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }
```

Is there a way to (after this) execute the scripts saved in .sql file to create the tables and values for this new data base?

Comment: How many users do you anticipate? Have you thought about update scripts? This sounds like a very painful architecture to me. Would be much simpler to add a column for UserID to every table and make sure  that every query has that additional check.

Comment: Side note: "searched alot" is not useful information in the post. Please either show what approaches you've found that did not work (i.e. link + one sentence description would be perfect) or don't add such text at all. I.e. "tried [Create DB programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015142/creating-a-database-programmatically-in-sql-server) but XXXX prevents me from doing it")

Comment: @SeanLange this is for a web version of a software developed by my company. If only 20% of our clients adhere we're talking about 350 to 450 clients wich can have more than 1 different user and in the tables they'll include their own clients. I think it's for the best to keep a database for each client.

Comment: So when you update the software you have to update 350-450 databases. That does not sound like fun to me.

Comment: to answer your question you would create a script to CREATE DATABASE xxx etc

Comment: I think i didn't explain myself well, i'll edit the question and try to be clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c-sharp#answer-7741105).

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("data source=MySource; initial catalog=MYNewDB;persist security info=True;user id=MyUser;password=MyPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True; "))
{
   string script = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Somewhere\...\script.sql");

   // split script on GO command
   IEnumerable<string> commandStrings = Regex.Split(script, @"^\s*GO\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

   conn.Open();
   foreach (string commandString in commandStrings)
   {
      if (commandString.Trim() != "")
      {
         using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandString, conn))
         {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
      }
   }
   conn.Close();
}
```