# Oracle: correct way to prevent SQL Injection when using parameters is not possible

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-injection

I have a C# program which does some operations on Oracle database. One of the operations - create a new account.

```
CREATE USER {login} IDENTIFIED BY {password}
```

The problem is that I can't use Parameters here, because this type of query doesn't support it. I didn't find exact documentation about why it's not supported, but I suppose it's similar to what is described here (DDL operations don't support parameters): [How to use SqlCommand to CREATE DATABASE with parameterized db name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523989/how-to-use-sqlcommand-to-create-database-with-parameterized-db-name)

So my question would be - how to prevent SQL injection in the following case in **Oracle** specifically? Should it be some regex to validate login and password? If so, what can it be? It's not clear, because, as Oracle docs [says](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129) **"Nonquoted identifiers cannot be Oracle SQL reserved words. Quoted identifiers can be reserved words, although this is not recommended."** How can I check that my login is not ANY of reserved words? And so on.

For MS SQL I have similar situation

```
CREATE LOGIN {login} WITH PASSWORD=N'{password}'
```

and I'm solving it in the following way: I escape login with

```
new SqlCommandBuilder().QuoteIdentifier(name);
```

and password with simple

```
password.Replace("'", "''");
```

because it's a literal in the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this case you could use [DBMS_ASSERT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_assert.htm#CHDIFDJE), following an example of a stored procedure using DBMS_ASSERT  to check the name of the user:

```
create or replace procedure procedure_create_user
   (user_name IN varchar2 , u_password IN varchar2 )
  IS
    tmp_query varchar(150);
    user_name_upper varchar(30) := UPPER(user_name) ;
  BEGIN
    tmp_query := 'create user C##' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(user_name_upper) || ' identified by ' || u_password;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( tmp_query );

    tmp_query := 'grant create session to C##' || user_name_upper ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( tmp_query );
  END;
  /
```

Then you can call this procedure and create the user:

```
exec procedure_create_user('alessio', 'llll');
```

From C# you should be able to call the stored procedure in this way:

```
 using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection("ConnectionString"))
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("procedure_create_user", connection))             
    {
          command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          command.Parameters.Add("user_name", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "alessio";
          command.Parameters.Add("u_password", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "llll";

          connection.Open();
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

For the password field you should do the same, but you need to be careful if you want to allow some character that is not allowed by the `simple_sql_name` ... Probably it won't be necessary for the password since even if they are injection code there they shouldn't be able to do much harm since after the identification section(`IDENTIFIED BY`) the `CREATE USER` procedure should only accept a limited set of keywords, so if you set even the PASSWORD EXPIRE afterwards, there is probably not much they can inject without getting an error ...

Comment: Thanks, sounds like it's the best approach. I'm not sure about password though - simple_sql_name doesn't conform with requirements to password. Probably I'll go with manual validation with regex as per requirements